# Recursively deny access but allow access to 1 file in subdirectory?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm currently denying access to all subdirectories and files using the following

```
<Directory /var/www/*>
    Allow from None
    Order allow,deny
</Directory>
```

How would I add an exception to allow access to a file with the path `/var/www/subdir/file.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the following snippet to your configuration:

```
<Location /subdir/file.php>
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Location>
```

to allow access from all to this single file.